# Use auto generate key in asp.net

Tags: ado.net, identity-column

I have a field which is an auto generated primary key. Now I need to insert a row with this field as one of its column. How should I create "insert" arguments?

```
    protected  void  Button1_Click(object  sender, EventArgs  e) 
    {
            new DataSet1TableAdapters.MemberTableAdapter().Insert(
                 1,TextBox5.Text,TextBox6.Text,
                 int.Parse(TextBox8.Text),
                 TextBox9.Text,
                 TextBox10.Text);
     }
```

I got **Error**:

```
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Member' when 
  IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."
```

Actually I shouldn't insert any value for first argument because it's auto generated. but this error appear after using this style:

```
   protected  void  Button1_Click(object  sender, EventArgs  e)
    {
            new  DataSet1TableAdapters.MemberTableAdapter().Insert(
            TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text, int.Parse(TextBox8.Text),
            TextBox9.Text, TextBox10.Text);
    }
```

And I get:

```
 Error:No overload for method insert take 5 argument
```

So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're doing, It seems your table adapter is expecting the field, but the DB won't allow it. You should remove the parameter from your table adapder

Comment: Open table design and try to set `Is identity` to **yes**

Comment: @satindersingh It's yes already.

Comment: @user1181065 I edited your question's tags, dropped asp.net and added ado.net - why did you change it back? Your problem is in ado.net, not in asp.net !